# jQuery Checkbox select all, select none and select group

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form with checkboxes split into groups with a radio button group to select all and select none. The checkbox labels will get a class attached to them (for the css to make it an image). The problem I am having is that the script loops back onto itself within the conditional statement and I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure it out.

I have created a JSFiddle page with the code here http://jsfiddle.net/jaread83/V5SSM/

What I want it to do:

SelectAll is clicked, all checkbox labels get the class of 'c_on' and all checkboxes get checked.

SelectNone is clicked, all checkbox labels have the 'c_on' class removed and all checkbox inputs get unchecked.

When a section_label gets clicked, all checkbox labels within that section get 'c_on' and also checked and then when it is unchecked, to remove the checked status and remove the 'c_on' class from that section only.

When a single checkbox label is clicked that isn't a section_label, that single item label gets 'c_on' class added and the checkbox gets the checked status.

The html:

```
<div class="form">
<div class="document">
    <div class="section inline">
        <label class="label_radio lightblue" id="selectAllButton" for="selectAll">
            <input type="radio" name="masscheck" id="selectAll" />Select all</label>
    </div>
    <div class="section inline">
        <label class="label_radio lightblue" id="selectNoneButton" for="selectNone">
            <input type="radio" name="masscheck" id="selectNone" />Select none</label>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="document">
    <div class="section">
        <label class="label_check section_label blue" for="docs_1131">
            <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1131" name="docs" value="1131" />Title page</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="document">
    <div class="section">
        <label class="label_check section_label blue" for="docs_1118">
            <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1118" name="docs" value="1118" />
            Section 1
        </label>

        <blockquote>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1119">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1119" name="docs" value="1119" />
                    Subsection 1.1
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1120">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1120" name="docs" value="1120" />
                    Subsection 1.2
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1121">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1121" name="docs" value="1121" />
                    Subsection 1.3
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1122">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1122" name="docs" value="1122" />
                    Subsection 1.4
                </label>
            </div>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="document">
    <div class="section">
        <label class="label_check section_label blue" for="docs_1123">
            <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1123" name="docs" value="1123" />
            Section 2
        </label>

        <blockquote>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1124">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1124" name="docs" value="1124" />
                    Subsection 2.1
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1125">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1125" name="docs" value="1125" />
                    Subsection 2.2
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1126">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1126" name="docs" value="1126" />
                    Subsection 2.3
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1127">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1127" name="docs" value="1127" />
                    Subsection 2.4
                </label>
            </div>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>


<button type="submit" class="icon icon-arrow-white">Submit</button>
```

The JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//check all and checknone
  $('#selectAll').click(function() {
      var selectAllButton = $('#selectAllButton');
      var selectNoneButton = $('#selectNoneButton');
      var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
      var checklabels = $('.label_check');
      checkboxes.attr('checked', true);
      checklabels.addClass('c_on');
      selectAllButton.addClass('c_on');
      selectNoneButton.removeClass('c_on');
  });

  $('#selectNone').click(function() {
      var selectAllButton = $('#selectAllButton');
      var selectNoneButton = $('#selectNoneButton');
      var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
      var checklabels = $('.label_check');
      checkboxes.attr('checked', false);
      checklabels.removeClass('c_on');
      selectNoneButton.addClass('c_on');
      selectAllButton.removeClass('c_on');
  });

  //check all within section
  $('.section .section_label').click(function(){
    var p = $(this).parent();

    if($(this).hasClass('c_on')){
      // remove the checkbox classes on sub sections
      p.find('.subsection').find('label').removeClass('c_on');
      // remove the class from the thing we have clicked
      $(this).removeClass('c_on');
    } else {
      p.find('.subsection').find('label').addClass('c_on');
      $(this).addClass('c_on');
    }
  });

 });
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `prop()` instead of `attr()` to check the checkboxes, check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V5SSM/1/)

**Update**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//check all and checknone
  $('#selectAll').click(function() {
      var selectAllButton = $('#selectAllButton');
      var selectNoneButton = $('#selectNoneButton');
      var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox');
      var checklabels = $('.label_check');
      checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
      checklabels.addClass('c_on');
      selectAllButton.addClass('c_on');
      selectNoneButton.removeClass('c_on');
  });

  $('#selectNone').click(function() {
      var selectAllButton = $('#selectAllButton');
      var selectNoneButton = $('#selectNoneButton');
      var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox');
      var checklabels = $('.label_check');
      checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
      checklabels.removeClass('c_on');
      selectNoneButton.addClass('c_on');
      selectAllButton.removeClass('c_on');
  });

  //check all within section
    $('.section .section_label input:checkbox').click(function(){

    var p = $(this).parents('.section');

     p.find('div.subsection input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    if(!this.checked){
       $(this).parent().removeClass('c_on')            
      // remove the checkbox classes on sub sections
      p.find('.subsection').find('label').removeClass('c_on');
      // remove the class from the thing we have clicked
      $(this).removeClass('c_on');
    } else {
       $(this).parent().addClass('c_on')
        p.find('.subsection').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true)
      p.find('.subsection').find('label').addClass('c_on');
      $(this).addClass('c_on');
    }
  });

 });
```

let me know if you've any query or concern in this.

Glad to help you

Comment: That works brilliantly! The selecting of all boxes works great and the group selection is awesome!Now all I need is to extend it a little more to work on each individual checkbox. I need to make the section checkboxes to be a bit more generic than specific to IDs as this form is being generated and could end up a lot bigger in terms of the sections.

Comment: you can use `$('.section .section_label input:checkbox')` instead of `$('#docs_1118, #docs_1123')` check my update

Comment: That is amazing and it works beautifully. But now it wont tick each individual checkbox in the same way when done seperately. Thank you so much for your time, I was going crazy trying to get this to work.

Comment: Of course, given you a big green tick. You have been an amazing help! I should be able to finish this now!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$('#selectAllButton').on('click', function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true).closest('label').addClass('c_on');
});
$('#selectNoneButton').on('click', function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false).closest('label').removeClass('c_on');
});

$('.section .section_label input').click(function () {

    var chckClass = "";
    if (!this.checked) {
        chckClass = ""; 
    } else {
       chckClass = "c_on"
    }
    $(this).closest('.section').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked).closest('label').removeClass("c_on").addClass(chckClass);
});
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
     var chckClass = "";
    if (!this.checked) {
        chckClass = ""; 
    } else {
       chckClass = "c_on"
    }
    $(this).closest('label').removeClass('c_on').addClass(chckClass);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/V5SSM/2/)

Comment: Wow this is great and has been completely rewritten to be shorter! Thank you!